# Select onChange preview svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have little html experience and no java experience and am trying to display an SVG image once the option is selected. Currently the code is at this, which displays a gif image:

```
<SELECT NAME=SIGN_NFPA onchange=\"
  this.form.SIGN_PIC1.selectedIndex = 0;
  var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
  var lnk = (id) ? 'SignNFPA/'+id+'.gif' : 'images/blank.gif';
  window.document.SIGN_PIC1.src = lnk;
  return true;
\">
```

Now we are generating files and want to replace that with this line of code

```
<SELECT NAME=SIGN_NFPA onchange='$("img[name=SIGN_PIC1]").prop('src',"SignNFPA?nfpa="+this.value);'>
```

but I keep getting a syntax error, what am I doing wrong? I know it should be a function in onchange but my coworker says you can input code directly instead. Thanks.

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: Compile Error in module CEMS::Applet::SignRecord: syntax error at module.pm line 688, near "$("img"
Compilation failed in require at (eval 17) line 2.

Comment: As you are using jQuery, use jQuery *event handlers* (and `data-` attributes) and not inline event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is nested single-quotes around "src". This is causing it to see `onchange='$("img[name=SIGN_PIC1]").prop('` as a complete attribute, followed by garbage.

Change those to be a compatible set of quotes:

```
<SELECT NAME=SIGN_NFPA onchange='$("img[name=SIGN_PIC1]").prop("src","SignNFPA?nfpa="+this.value);'>
```

but this would read as *more* "standard" like this:

```
<SELECT NAME="SIGN_NFPA" onchange="$('img[name=SIGN_PIC1]').prop('src','SignNFPA?nfpa='+this.value);">
```

But *as your are using jQuery*, I would strongly suggest moving to using a jQuery event handler, and appropriate `data-` attributes and not use a inline handler.

e.g. something like the following (not checked for errors - just a guide)

### HTML:

```
<SELECT NAME="SIGN_NFPA" \>
```

### jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $('[name="SIGN_NFPA"]').change(function(e){
       var $signpic1 = $('[name="SIGN_PIC1"]')
       $signpic1.val(0);
       var id = $(this).val();
       var lnk = (id) ? 'SignNFPA/'+id+'.gif' : 'images/blank.gif';
       $signpic1.attr("src", lnk);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes when adding attributes in HTML. Specially in value

```
<select name="SIGN_NFPA">
  <!--options-->
</select>
```

Using [event Handler](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-handler-attachment/) in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='SIGN_NFPA']").change(function() {
        $('img[name=SIGN_PIC1]').prop('src', 'SignNFPA?nfpa=' + this.value);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was because I was in quote hell, probably should've mentioned that but I'm relatively new to programming. I'm in a perl file using html thats using jquery and the $ sign was being interpreted as a scalar, causing a syntax error. Also simultaneously in quote hell

Comment: Shame you did not mention that. However, that does not change the advice, from both other answers:  Using inline event handlers is a maintenance nightmare and you should consider doing it "the jQuery way" instead :)